# genymotion Could not find a player plugin

Tags: android, genymotion

I want to install  genymotion https://www.genymotion.com/download/ but i have a problem with virtual devices when i want to start.

The instalation procedure is good,
the creation of virtual devices is good too.
but when i want to start a virtual device, without prompt any screen, the device appears OFF.

this is the string that de console output

```
"Could not find a player plugin"
```

my setup is

```
Linux  5.10.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.140-1 (2022-09-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
```

I am using vscode, android studio and the android sdk emulator, all works.

THe logs ouputs this.

```
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] - Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] - Vary: Accept-Encoding
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] - Server: cloudflare
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] - CF-RAY: 7571537bfa2f954e-LIM
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] HTTP content (first 127 bytes): error code: 1015
 [Genymotion:29139] [warning] [tokenError] AbstractAuthService::Error::TooManyRequests "Error transferring https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activa
 [Genymotion:29139] [warning] License validity reaches the minimum acceptable value.
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] GET "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Google Nexus 7 2013")
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] Genymotion is up-to-date
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] Genymotion template count: 114
 [Genymotion:29139] [warning] Template cache from "/home/yvasquez/.Genymobile/Genymotion/templates/sharedTemplates.list" is outdated, ignoring it
 [Genymotion:29139] [warning] Template cache from "/home/yvasquez/.Genymobile/Genymotion/templates/sharedTemplates.list" is outdated, ignoring it
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] "Server templates: 114, local templates: 45, merge: 114"
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] [findClosestTemplate] uuid "3ca42f69-ff08-42b3-8d78-2ccb617e55f2" platform "tp" androidVersion "4.4.4"
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] Starting device "6e52c9d9-024d-4c34-a8be-d2f5a0497a33" AbstractDeviceListController::DeviceUpdatePolicy::REQUIRED_UPDATE
 [Genymotion:29139] [info] setDeviceStatus "6e52c9d9-024d-4c34-a8be-d2f5a0497a33" DeviceListModel::Status::BOOTING
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] [findClosestTemplate] uuid "3ca42f69-ff08-42b3-8d78-2ccb617e55f2" platform "tp" androidVersion "4.4.4"
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "--machinereadable", "6e52c9d9-024d-4c34-a8be-d2f5a0497a33")
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] [findClosestTemplate] uuid "3ca42f69-ff08-42b3-8d78-2ccb617e55f2" platform "tp" androidVersion "4.4.4"
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] Device is up to date
 [Genymotion:29139] [info] setDeviceStatus "6e52c9d9-024d-4c34-a8be-d2f5a0497a33" DeviceListModel::Status::OFF
 [Genymotion:29139] [debug] [findClosestTemplate] uuid "3ca42f69-ff08-42b3-8d78-2ccb617e55f2" platform "tp" androidVersion "4.4.4"
```

Please someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A required system library is missing. That's probably because you are using an unsupported desktop. Try installing Gnome, KDE or MATE desktop.

Comment: Julien thanks for your answer,
I am using awesome desktop,
I will try with another desktop as you suggests,
but i am not really happy to think about change my desktop 
Thanks again.
PD: Sorry for my english

Comment: I know what you mean, but Genymotion has been designed to work with common desktops, not with "exotic" desktops such as Awesome :-)

Comment: I've recentrly tried with another desktop an genymotion works and the simulator too.
I am very satisfied with your answer, Thanks
have a good day.